# Nape Physics AS3 - Simple Tennis Game

Tags: actionscript-3, physics, game-physics, nape

I'm developing a very simple tennis game using [Nape](http://napephys.com/):

A rigid object (a tennis racket) follows the mouse coordinates and hits another object that has the property of bouncing.

I read many examples of Nape, but I don't know how to setup the tennis racket: which properties I must use when I create the "Body()" instance of the racket.

Any tutorial, snippet or advice is welcome friends,

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think the demos on the Nape page should get you going pretty well. There's code for all of them there.

http://napephys.com/samples.html#

Looks to me like the basic simulation one would be a good starting point since the circle is much like a tennis racket.

Comment: You're right David. The big circle following mouseX and mouseY can be used as the "racket". Thanks.